# KeyError when accessing Pandas DataFrame using MultiIndex

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

A `pandas.DataFrame` have it's `MultiIndex` created as shown:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': 'foo bar foo bar foo bar foo foo'.split(),
                   'B': 'one one two three three two four three'.split(),
                   'C': np.arange(8), 'D': np.arange(8) * 2})

df = df.set_index(['A','B'])
```

This creates a `DataFrame``:

```
           C   D
A   B           
foo one    0   0
bar one    1   2
foo two    2   4
bar three  3   6
foo three  4   8
bar two    5  10
foo four   6  12
    three  7  14
```

**Problem:** Why do you get a `KeyError: 'foo'` when trying to select using `df['foo']`? Similarly, `df['foo', 'one']` and `df['foo']['one']`.

Furthermore,the MultiIndex did not group all the `foo`s together under `A`? Is it necessary to group them together, like :

```
          A         B
one 1 -0.732470 -0.313871
    2 -0.031109 -2.068794
    3  1.520652  0.471764
two 1 -0.101713 -1.204458
    2  0.958008 -0.455419
    3 -0.191702 -0.915983
```

Answer (score 3):

`df['foo']` tries to select column `foo` and thus generates `KeyError` as there is no `foo` column. I guess you meant to do `df.loc['foo']` and `df.loc['foo', 'one']`.

Comment: Thanks! `df.loc['foo', 'one']` also returns a warning `PerformanceWarning: indexing past lexsort depth may impact performance.`. Should we be concerned?